# Debug in settings is causing issues with images in media folder

Tags: python, html, css, django

In Django, I have set **DEBUG = False** and **ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1']**.
But due to it, images tend to get hide even if they are shown in the **TERMINAL**.
I always do clear the cache of both Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox.

[image]

*Below is the screenshot from chrome*

[image]

*Also their seems to an issue with Firefox*

At a moment, Chrome was showing all the images while firefox didn't show any of them in the below screenshot
[image]

Comment: With `DEBUG=False` django will not serve your static files. See more https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#managing-static-files-e-g-images-javascript-css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output in your terminal prints a 404 error, meaning the files can't be found. Did you run the [collectstatic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic) command? This copies the static files (images, javascript) to your static directory from where they can be served by your webserver.